# TS2322 - type X is not assignable to type Y, but all fields in Y are contained in X

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

So I'm using react-redux combineReducers here.

```
export interface OurState {widgets: WidgetState; currentView: string;}

export const ourReducer = combineReducers<OurState, ValidAction>({ widgets, currentView });


export type ViewActionType = SwitchViewAction;  
export type ValidAction = WidgetActionType | ViewActionType;
```

Error message is T2322, in ourReducer, saying Type 'ValidAction' is not assignable to type 'SwitchViewAction'

I think it clearly is assignable to this type.  How am I wrong?

These actions are actions for the dispatch.

Comment: You can assign `SwitchViewAction` to `ValidAction`, not the other way around.

Comment: If I write AnyAction to replace ValidAction, it still doesn't work.  Surely I can assign AnyAction to SwitchViewAction?

Comment: Nope, that's hot how types works. You can assign subtypes to supertype. You cannot assign supertype to subtype without a cast.

Comment: Hmm i see.  Why doesn't 'any' work, do you know?

Answer (score 0):

> I think it clearly is assignable to this type. How am I wrong?

Yes.

> Type 'ValidAction' is not assignable to type 'SwitchViewAction'

Because `ValidAction` might be of type `WidgetActionType` (because of the `|`).

Comment: Ok, thank you.  Is there an easy fix?  If I replace ValidAction with AnyAction, I get, type 'AnyAction' is not assignable to type 'WidgetActionType'